# Link en React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Estoy aprendiendo React y me encuentro en la tarea de asignarle a un componente  diferentes rutas. Intento definirlas en las props del componente pero no lo consigo.
Aqui el codigo:

```
const IntroJuegos = () => {
    const [popupVisible, setPopupVisible] = useState(false)


    return (
        <div className='container mt-3'>

            <IntroJuego src={minJuegoPrueba} />
            {popupVisible ? <PopUp onClick={() =>
                    setPopupVisible(false)} /> : null}

            <Button
                onClick={() =>
                    setPopupVisible(true)}
                 name='DESAFIAR AMIGO'

            />
             <Button
                onClick={() => 
                <Link to='/promociones'/>} 

                name='ELEGIR PREMIO'       
            />
            <Button
                onClick={() => <Link to='/promociones' />
                    }
                name='VER PUNTAJES'       
            />

        </div>


    )
}

export default IntroJuegos
```

El primer boton abre un pop Up pero los dos siguientes necesito que vayan a otras paginas de la app. Alguien me podria orientar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para redireccionar al usuario deberias utilizar Redirect.

```
<Redirect to="/promociones" />
```

Ten en cuenta que al renderizarse, redireccionará al usuario a la ruta especificada. Te recomiendo utilizar un estado, en donde tengas dos propiedades. Una con la que puedas checar si hay o no que redirigir al usuario a una ruta especifica, otra en la que guardes la url a la que será redireccionado.

```
this.state =  {
     // Cuando des click al boton puedes cambiar esta propiedad a true
     PendienteRedireccion: false,
     // y aquí actualizar la url
     UrlRedireccion: '/'
}
```

Quedaría algo asi:

```
<Button
onClick={() => this.setState({PendienteRedireccion: true, UrlRedireccion: '/promociones'}) }
name='VER PUNTAJES'/>


{

    if( this.state.PendienteRedireccion)
    {
        let Uri = this.state.UrlRedireccion;
        this.setState({PendienteRedireccion: false, UrlRedireccion: '/'}
        return <Redirect to={Uri} />
    }
}
```

Comment: Estaria ok asi?

const [PendienteRedireccion, UrlRedireccion] = useState(false)

    return (

            <Button
            onClick={() => PendienteRedireccion(true), UrlRedireccion('/promociones')}
            name='VER PUNTAJES'/>

            
            {PendienteRedireccion ? () => let Url = UrlRedireccion, <Redirect to={Url} /> : null}